# What is the most Pythonic way to interleave text file contents?

Tags: python

Python question:

If I have a list of files, how do I print line #1 from each file, then
line #2, etc.? (I'm a Python newbie, obviously...)

Example:

```
file1:
foo1
bar1

file2:
foo2
bar2

file3:
foo3
bar3
```

Function call:

```
names = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]
myfct(names)
```

Desired output:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3

bar1
bar2
bar3
```

This is how I did it, but I'm sure there is a more elegant, Pythonic way:

```
def myfct(files):
    file_handlers = []
    for myfile in files:
        file_handlers.append(open(myfile))
    while True:
        done = False
        for handler in file_handlers:
            line = handler.readline()
            eof = len(line) == 0 # wrong
            if (eof):
                done = True
                break
            print(line, end = "")
        print()
        if done == True:
            break
```

P.S.: I'm using Python 2.6 with `from __future__ import print_function`.

Answer (score 8):

```
for lines in itertools.izip(*file_handlers):
  sys.stdout.write(''.join(lines))
```

Comment: Thanks! In that example, how would I put a blank line between the lines `n` and lines `n+` of the different files (see "desired output")?

Comment: @Frank: print a new line at the end of each loop. One iteration of the loop is a line from each file. So your newline would go after the sys.stdout

Comment: Just change the `sys.stdout.write()` into a `print()`.

Comment: @Frank ``sys.stdout.write(''.join(lines)+"\n")``

Comment: Thanks, that was easy. One more question: What does the `*` do in `*file_handlers`?

Comment: Positional expansion. It expands the iterable into positional arguments.

Comment: How can I avoid opening all files in a loop and storing the `file_handlers` in advance? I'm sure you can put the `open` command into the `for` loop as well, maybe using `lambda`?

Comment: That will bring a world of hurt. Open them all in advance.

Comment: @Frank: Try using this with a combination of andrew cookes example using contexts

Answer (score 4):

```
> cat foo
foo 1
foo 2
foo 3
foo 4
> cat bar
bar 1
bar 2
> cat interleave.py 
from itertools import izip_longest
from contextlib import nested

with nested(open('foo'), open('bar')) as (foo, bar):
    for line in (line for pair in izip_longest(foo, bar)
                      for line in pair if line):
        print line.strip()
> python interleave.py 
foo 1
bar 1
foo 2
bar 2
foo 3
foo 4
```

compared to other answers here:

- files are closed on exit
- izip_longest doesn't stop when one file stops
- efficient use of memory

or, for multiple files (`filenames` is a list of files):

```
with nested(*(open(file) for file in filenames)) as handles:
    for line in (line for tuple in izip_longest(*handles)
                      for line in tuple if line):
        print line.strip()
```

Comment: I like the inclusion using contexts

Comment: Okay, but that works only for a prespecified number of files (here: 2 files).

Comment: Hey andrew, what do you think about making it a bit more dynamic in case there are more file names? Something like this: http://pastebin.com/xEr2hpB5

Comment: @Frank: See my previous comment

Comment: oh, that's nicer; i will steal that syntax.  shouldn't use map :o)

Comment: @andrewcooke: Actually I think its perfectly clear how to adapt. You just pass it a list of filenames :-) And I liked it better with the map. It was just as easy to read and a shorter line

Answer (score 1):

If all your files have the same number of lines, or if you want to stop as soon as any file is exhausted, Ignacio's answer is perfect.  If you want to support files of different lengths, though, you should use the "round robin" recipe from the `itertools` documentation:

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))

sys.stdout.writelines(roundrobin(*file_handlers))
```